# Excel Dashboard data connection drops

Tags: microsoft-excel, query, dashboard

I have a setup to display a status/dashboard of sorts, essentially a log that is updated from another computer. It works via Excel, like this:

- Someone adds data to a table in "Log_Source.xlsx" which is located on a network share, and saves it.
- The dashboard computer (which is an Intel Compute Stick (Windows 10 Home) and a wall-mounted monitor) has a local file, "Log_Dashboard.xlsx" with a data connection to the source file on the network. The query refreshes every minute. This way the dashboard can pull and display the data, almost real-time, without locking the file for editing.

**The Problem:**

Every few days, I will get a message on the dashboard to the effect of, the data source could not be found. And it will no longer update the data. Closing and reopening Log_Dashboard.xlsx fixes it, but how can I prevent this from occurring?

**What I've tried:**

- In Windows power settings: Changed to High Performance plan. Set hard disk to never turn off. Set Wireless Adapter to Maximum Performance.
- Scheduled an AutoHotKey script to run every 12 hours, that just moves the mouse back and forth. I thought that might prevent the computer from going into a sleep state, if that was the issue.
- Added a macro to the Excel file that closes and reopens it every hour. Seeing as that's how I manually fix the issue each time, I thought that would take care of it, but it's still happening.

Any suggestions? Or if there's another approach to setting up a dashboard display like this I'm open to that to...
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a pattern to the error? Or is it random? Is it possible it is related to it not being able to refresh while someone has the data source file open?

Comment: @CharlieRB The problem is *usually*  in the morning, after the computer had been idle the whole night. I wouldn't call it a pattern but that's why I thought it was a power saving-type cause. The source file being open does not affect its ability to refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting what worked for me just in case anyone else with a similar issue stumbles upon this in the future:

I was never able to nail down why the data connection kept dropping. I switched the "dashboard" computer from a Wifi-connected Intel Compute Stick to an old Ethernet-connected compact desktop. That helped somewhat but I still experienced data connection drops, along with other Excel errors, like "Out of memory".

Here's the workaround that finally worked for me, in my situation:

I inserted a module into the Excel file ("Log_Dashboard.xlsm") with the following code:

```
Sub WorkbookSaveCycle()

ThisWorkbook.Save
PID = Shell("cmd /k @echo off & echo Restarting Dashboard, please wait... & @echo off & timeout /t 4 /nobreak & ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\excel.exe"" """ & Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName & """ & exit", vbMaximizedFocus)
Application.Quit

End Sub
```

This simply saves the workbook, runs a shell command that displays a message that the dashboard is restarting (in case anyone is looking at the screen at the time), and then re-opens the Excel file after waiting a few seconds for it to close. (`excel.exe` filepath may have to be changed if using a different version of Office)

Then I put this in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.DisplayFullScreen = True
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "WorkbookSaveCycle"

End Sub
```

When the Excel file opens, this sets it to fullscreen, then, after waiting the pre-defined amount of time (15 minutes here), calls the above `WorkbookSaveCycle` macro. Which just sets the cycle in motion again by closing and re-opening the file.

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but it has been basically rock-solid stable since implementing these changes.